# How to install gcc-3.4 and g++-3.4 on latest ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, installation, g++

I have Ubuntu 20.10 LTS and want to use g++-3.4 to build things. Old things.

After googling like mad about 2 hrs and trying to add different package repositories for apt-get I finally came to conclusion that auto-update just does not work. If anyone is struggling with the same problem or have a solution - be my guest.

Comment: What software is required GCC version 3.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **only** solution that worked for me is:

### Manual installing of .deb packages

*(sad programmer noises)*

1. Go to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/
2. Download all .deb packages for gcc compiler version you want, f.e.:

> ```
> gpc-2.1-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> cpp-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb       lib32g2c0_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> g++-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb       libg2c0_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> g77-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb       libg2c0-dev_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> gcc-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb       libstdc++6-dbg_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> gcc-3.4-base_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb  libstdc++6-dev_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> ```

3. Manually install them by running command, f.e.:

> ```
> sudo dpkg -i ./gcc-3.4-base_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb 
> sudo dpkg -i ./cpp-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> sudo dpkg -i ./gcc-3.4_3.4.6-6ubuntu5_amd64.deb
> ```
>
> and so on...

Check the console output errors about package dependencies to figure out the package install order.

- *If you encounter error (bug probably) about crossdependency of "g++..." package to "libstdc++..." package and v.v. then run install command to update libstdc++ package with exact version number, f.e.:*

> ```
> sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
> ```

4. **Hooray!** Use installed gcc (g++) version by, f.e.:

> ```
> g++-3.4 -v
> ```

Comment: What is reason you download and install other than "gcc-3.4" file?